# How to write this WHERE filter in my T-SQL Query that will cater for 2 conditions to be met?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table called ResStayDate which lists all reservations made on a property by date. Here is an extract of the table:

```
 ResaID    StayDate      PkgPlanCode      RateAmt
 61200     2015-01-11      COGB              0.00
 61200     2015-01-11      G1A810          152.00
 61200     2015-01-11      G1A810          152.00
 61200     2015-01-11      G1A810          152.00
 63500     2015-02-04      R2AI            125.00
 63500     2015-02-05      R2AI            125.00
 73850     2015-05-10      COGB              0.00
 73850     2015-05-10      G2450           169.00
 68901     2015-05-15      COFR              0.00
 68901     2015-05-15      COFR              0.00
```

I want a query that will output all the ResaIDs (plus the remaining columns of that table) which contain at least one StayDate with the PkgPlanCode "CO..." AND its corresponding RateAmt = 0. If all StayDates of a particular ResaID have PkgPlanCodes starting with "CO..." and their corresponding RateAmt = 0,then these ResaIDs should be excluded in the output.

In other words, my output should look like this:

```
ResaID    StayDate      PkgPlanCode      RateAmt
 61200     2015-01-11      COGB              0.00
 61200     2015-01-11      G1A810          152.00
 61200     2015-01-11      G1A810          152.00
 61200     2015-01-11      G1A810          152.00
 73850     2015-05-10      COGB              0.00
 73850     2015-05-10      G2450           169.00
```

The query should exclude ResaID 63500 (since it does not contain any PkgPlanCode starting with "CO..." and having RateAmt = 0) and also exclude ResaID 68901 (as the latter has all of its StayDate with PkgPlanCode starting with "CO..." and RateAmt = 0)

My query stands as follows as at now (as I am stuck as to how to handle the condition in the query):

```
SELECT *

FROM ResStayDate

WHERE.......
```

Comment: To clarify: if you had one more record for ResaID 68901 with a `COGB` Package and RateAmt of `152.00`, would you want to see those 68901 records?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn No, I would want that record to be excluded. You raise a very good point though as I do have those situations in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a couple of [CTEs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx) to assess the conditions required and then use [windowed aggregates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to determine if the condition is *sometimes* true across `ResaID` values:

```
declare @t table (ResaID int,StayDate date,PkgPlanCode varchar(17),RateAmt decimal(13,2))
insert into @t(ResaID,StayDate,PkgPlanCode,RateAmt) values
 (61200,'20150111','COGB'  ,  0.00),
 (61200,'20150111','G1A810',152.00),
 (61200,'20150111','G1A810',152.00),
 (61200,'20150111','G1A810',152.00),
 (63500,'20150204','R2AI'  ,125.00),
 (63500,'20150205','R2AI'  ,125.00),
 (73850,'20150510','COGB'  ,  0.00),
 (73850,'20150510','G2450' ,169.00),
 (68901,'20150515','COFR'  ,  0.00),
 (68901,'20150515','COFR'  ,  0.00)

 ;With Assessment as (
    select ResaID,StayDate,PkgPlanCode,RateAmt,
         CASE WHEN PkgPlanCode like 'CO%' and RateAmt=0.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Cond
    from @t
), Groups as (
    select *,
        MIN(Cond) OVER (PARTITION BY ResaID) as MinCond,
        MAX(Cond) OVER (PARTITION BY ResaID) as MaxCond
    from
        Assessment
)
select * from Groups where MinCond < MaxCond
```

Result:

```
ResaID      StayDate   PkgPlanCode       RateAmt    Cond        MinCond     MaxCond
----------- ---------- ----------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
61200       2015-01-11 COGB              0.00       1           0           1
61200       2015-01-11 G1A810            152.00     0           0           1
61200       2015-01-11 G1A810            152.00     0           0           1
61200       2015-01-11 G1A810            152.00     0           0           1
73850       2015-05-10 COGB              0.00       1           0           1
73850       2015-05-10 G2450             169.00     0           0           1
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Make it a composite `WHERE` condition like

```
WHERE PkgPlanCode LIKE 'CO%'
AND RateAmt = 0.00
```

Comment: Look again at the OPs expected results. How is your query going to return the row `73850     2015-05-10      G2450           169.00`?

Comment: @Rahul It won't work as it will also output ResaID 68901

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH COPkgs As 
(   -- IDs for reservations with a CO* Package and 0 rate
    SELECT DISTINCT ResaID FROM ResStayDate Where PkgPlanCode LIKE 'CO%' AND RateAmt = 0
),
NonCOPkgs As
(   -- IDs for reservartions with a non-CO package
    SELECT DISTINCT ResaID FROM ResStayDate Where PkgPlanCode NOT LIKE 'CO%'
)
-- Reservation records that match IDs from BOTH previous sets
SELECT r.*
FROM ResStayDate r
INNER JOIN COPkgs c ON c.ResaID = r.ResaID 
INNER JOIN NonCOPkgs n on n.ResaID = r.ResaID
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test your solution too and report back.